# Salesforce: utility to escape char from vf page?

Tags: salesforce

When passing value from salesforce to javascript I can simple do 
var test = '{!myname}';
But how can i escape this so that I can take care of name with symbol like single quote? 
I noticed String.escapeSingleQuote exists but can only be used in class not in vfpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the range of ["encoding functions"](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm) (bottom of the page).

```
var test = '{!JSENCODE(myname)}';
```

will be probably best. The help reference of these functions says that they work only in buttons/links but I've used them several times on VF pages. In fact they're recommended way of [strengthening your code against XSS etc attacks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm).

You could also use `<apex:outputField>` everywhere and fetch the content of fields by id for example. By default most tags that output text data have `escape="true"` set.